# allow html5 drag and show icon onDrag

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, openlayers

I have a div with an anchor and icon.

```
<a id="createWave_addStation"><img class="createWaveToolBarImg" 
src="img/mapIcons/ico_station.png"></a>
```

I drag this and want to drop it on an OpenLayers map. Because img's have draggable as default, I don't set it here. Now When I drag the icon, the img does not get dragged along so I only see the cursor. How can I show the icon od the dragged thing. This is my code, but it doesnt work.

```
$('#createWave_addStation').bind("dragstart", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log("drag start");
        enableGetMouseupEvent();
        var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
        dragIcon.src = ICO_STATION;
        dragIcon.width = 100;
        ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImg(dragIcon, -10, -10);
    });
```

Well the code itself works, but the img is not shown while dragging

Comment: What is `enableGetMouseupEvent()`?

Comment: @maenu: it's a custom function which enables the onmouseup event.

Comment: I tried running it without success in Chrome. For sure you should replace `setDragImg` with `setDragImage` according to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/editing.html#dom-datatransfer-setdragimage), and you may need to append the drag image to the DOM. Anyway, HTML5 drag and drop is still a mess, it will be hard to get a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked something together that works in Chrome, I didn't test it in any other browser.
A demo is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYzhb/).

Two things are important:

- an arbitrary element should have set `draggable="true"`
- the image you want to show while dragging should be preloaded, otherwise it will not show the first time.